# C std::lower_bound, use overloaded operator as Binary predicate comp?

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, lower-bound

I'm working on an assignment where we have to program multiple decks of cards that can interact with each other using vectors (e.g. removing one card from the main deck and adding it to another). The assignment states we must use an overloaded "smaller than" operator from our card struct to determine the correct order of cards by combining it with the std::lower_bound function. So far this is what I have:

```
void CardDeck::Add(const Card& card)
{
    m_Cards.insert(std::lower_bound(m_Cards.begin(),m_Cards.end(),card,*insert smaller than operator here*),card);
}
```

And the overloaded "smaller than" operator of the Card struct is as follows. It compares the rank and the suit of the cards based on a predetermined order in an enumeration:

```
friend bool operator< (const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs)
{
    if(lhs.m_Suit < rhs.m_Suit || (lhs.m_Suit == rhs.m_Suit && lhs.m_Rank < rhs.m_Rank))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. The assignment states we MUST use the overloaded operator. We're not allowed to make a simple "IsSmallerThan()" method of our own.

Many thanks.

EDIT: forgot to mark the problem. Extra info in comments.

Comment: What is your problem? (besides the superfluous comma)

Comment: So what's the issue? Is it a bug? Compiler error?

Comment: Also, notice that you're not returning anything in your operator < overload when the condition is false. That could be a silent error waiting to bite you...

Comment: @bstamour Woops I copy/pasted over the problem. The m_Cards.insert(), I need to specify what determines a card to be lower than the other at the end. i want to use my overloaded "smaller than" operator but I don't know if that's possible or how to write it. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Emvidasch see my answer below. Calling lower_bound without a comparator will use the operator < for the type by default.

Comment: @Emvidasch more to the point, it does so indirectly, as the default for lower-bound is `std::less<T>` (in the OP's case, `std::less<Card>`, which expands to simply eval `lhs < rhs` for the given `const Card&` arguments during comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `std::lower_bound` uses the less-than operator for the type behind the iterators. By defining your own `operator <`, lower_bound should just do the right thing. i.e. calling it like this

```
std::lower_bound(m_cards.begin(), m_cards.end(), card);
```

should work fine, give an appropriate `operator <` defined on card types.

One thing to point out is your code for `operator <` can be simplified to

```
friend bool operator< (const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs)
{
   return lhs.m_Suit < rhs.m_Suit || 
       (lhs.m_Suit == rhs.m_Suit && lhs.m_Rank < rhs.m_Rank);
}
```

(which also fixes a subtle bug in your code).

Comment: Affording strict weak ordering and not requiring the provision of an `operator ==` for the `m_Suit` data type, the first part of the right-side of the or-clause  should read `(!(rhs.m_Suit < lhs.m_Suit) && ...)` For scalers it should not make a difference, but for a more complex type (a custom type that implements `operator<`, the only operator mandated for strict weak ordering), it would be in keeping with the rest of the standard library ordering mantra. (and +1 on the answer, btw).

Comment: @WhozCraig I wanted to keep it to just cleaning what was presented in the question. Kudos on pointing out the correct way to implement the strict weak ordering :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
void CardDeck::Add(const Card& card)
{
    m_Cards.insert(std::lower_bound(m_Cards.begin(),m_Cards.end(),card,std::less<Card>()),card);
}
```

if you want to really provide a comparator. Since the default is already to use the above, you can also simply leave it out:

```
void CardDeck::Add(const Card& card)
{
    m_Cards.insert(std::lower_bound(m_Cards.begin(),m_Cards.end(),card),card);
}
```

You can also simplify your `operator<` (and make it less error-prone) by using `std::tie`:

```
friend bool operator< (const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.m_Suit, lhs.m_Rank) < std::tie(rhs.m_Suit, rhs.m_Rank);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, and I wish I could up-vote this again for the use of `std::tie` (love that thing).